# How to terminate a recursive function and return a value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to find a TextBox control inside a ASP.NET page using a recursive function. When this control is found, i would like to terminate the function and return it.

My main problem is that i'm unable to stop the recursive function and return the control.

Here's my code:

```
//execute recursive function to find a control in page by its id
TextBox textbox = GetTextBoxByID(controlCollection, id);

//recursive function
private TextBox GetTextBoxByID(ControlCollection controlCollection, string id)
{
    foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)control;

            if (tb.ID == id)
            {
                //return selected texbox and terminate this recursion
                return tb;
            }
        }

        if (control.HasControls())
        {
            GetTextBoxByID(control.Controls, id);
        }
    }

    //no control found return null
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing one more check, right here:

```
if (control.HasControls())
{
    var result = GetTextBoxByID(control.Controls, id);
    if (result != null)
        return result;
}
```

Comment: @ohmusama, you do, or else it won't go through all the possible branches, but terminate after first `foreach` pass, if that returns more elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = GetControlByName(this, "archHalfRoundWindowGroup");
}

public Control GetControlByName(Control Ctrl, string Name)
{
    Control ctrl = new Control();
    foreach (Control x in Ctrl.Controls)
    {
        if (x.Name == Name)
            return ctrl=x;
        if (x.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            ctrl= GetControlByName(x, Name);
            if (ctrl.Name != "")
                return ctrl;
        }
        if (ctrl.Name != "")
            return ctrl;
        }
        return ctrl;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain your example?